# Computational complexity of Initial Value Problems of ODEs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, na.numerical-analysis

Are there known results on computational complexity of [initial value problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) of ODEs? As my question may be somewhat vague, I want to mention that I'm mainly interested for results on the computational complexity of one-step methods ([Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)).

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I'am aware of the obvious time complexity results based on the number of function evaluations and the rate of convergence. I'm also aware of the PSPACE-completeness of the solution when the right-side of the equation $y'(t)=f(y(t),t))$ is polynomial-time computable and satisfies the weak Lipschitz condition w.r.t. $y(t)$ (which can be safely assumed in my case). All I want to know is what kind of conditions should an IVP obey to for its solution, $y(t)$, to be computable in polynomial time, if such conditions have beed found.

Comment: I found my answers in a paper by Kawamura ([link](http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~kawamura/papers/ivp_analytic/fulltext.pdf)) at last.